# Какие особенности и отличия css слайдера и слайдера на js?

Tags: javascript, css, слайдер

Переделал огромное количество слайдеров от готовых js аля вставил скрипт, картинки и забыл до css на строк 300~400. Но как ни искал а единственная разница которую я нашел это то, что css легче а на js больше готовых решений и их удобнее вставлять.

Кто разбирается, можете подсказать более детальные тонкости и особенности каждого?

Данная тема является причиной для споров уже достаточно долго но к консенсусу пока не приходили, так как и плюсы и минусы у каждого свои

Comment: Для каждой задачи есть свое решение, смотря что Вам нужно.

Слайдеры на CSS и JS это лишь инструмент, который Вы выбираете при постройке своего "сооружения".

Comment: В глобальном плане, на поддержание проекта это никак не отразится. Да, css более производителен, но в это же время многое не будет работать в старых версиях браузеров.. Ну и кроме этого, функционал слайдера на css будет крайне ограничен возможностями самого css.. Кто бы что не говорил, в этом плане js будет намного превосходить оппонента, по этой причине до сих пор множество вещей так и "создаются" с его помощью

Comment: Именно по той причине, которая описана в последнем абзаце вопроса, вопрос должен быть закрыт

Comment: Споров в добром смысле :)

Comment: Имел ввиду то, что когда меня спрашивали "на 'чем' сделать слайдер корректнее" то я говорил что можно его сделать как  на js так и на css и дальше не один раз  шел достаточно длинный диалог с аргументами в обе стороны, а было бы лучше если бы был "нокаутирующий" аргумент что бы сразу отнести определенный слайдер к определенным задачам ;)

Comment: @Mark тут не может быть никакого "нокаутирующего" аргуммента потому что это очень специфические вещи, где всё зависит от задачи.. Я не понимаю о каких спорах вообще речь, если абсолютно всё что можно сделать на css - можно сделать и на js, но в обратную сторону это не работает.. Самый простой пример - напишите слайдет который можно было бы листать "стрелками" на клавиатуре или останавливать пробелом. На js - лёгкая задача, на css - абсолютно не реализуемая..

Comment: Добавить слайд на css - лезь в код, добавляй ещё "секции" и т.п., а на js можно следать форму для добавления слайдов в "базу", с которой они будут выводится. (не влезло всё в пред коммент)

Comment: @InDevX, ну теоретически реализуемая: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-snappoints.

Comment: @Qwertiy во-первых, взглянуть на совместимость которую вы кинули и уже всё ясно становится, во-вторых, где тут реализация то? сами `CSS Scroll snap` это далеко не то, о чём я написал

Comment: @InDevX, я отвечал на _"напишите слайдет который можно было бы листать "стрелками" на клавиатуре или останавливать пробелом"_ - стрелки на клавиатуре - это прокрутка, для пробела я его в label оберну и дальше с чекбоксом по стандартной схеме. Что касается поддержки - именно поэтому я написал слово "теоретически".

Comment: @Qwertiy нет, стрелки на клавиатуре это не прокрутка, 2 совершенно разные вещи..

Comment: Блин) По моему 95% людей, которые везде говорят о производительности, в жизни еще не создавали проект такого масштаба, где каждая строчка на счету и нужно максимально грамотно всё оформить. Подключат по 20 библиотек скриптов и стилей, потом говорят о производительности одного слайдера))) В текущих реалиях и мощностях - вообще пофиг, на чем создавать стандартный слайдер на простенькой странице. И если это на JS реализуемо парой строчек - зачем запариваться над километровым CSS, чьи возможности к тому же еще и ограничены особенностями разметки.

Comment: осталось его сделать целиком на webgl и расслабиться

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, ты уверен, что плавная анимация слайдера на js реализуема меньшим количеством кода, чем на css? Что-то у меня наоборот получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Слайдер на css работает даже если у пользователя в браузере отключены скрипты.
2. При помощи js проще защиклить слайдер, чтобы он плавно переходил с последнего кадра на первый. Впрочем, на css тоже можно.
3. На js логичнее реализовывать фиксацию страниц выбором кнопки.
4. На css при использовании `animation-play-state: paused` возможна остановка между слайдами.
5. У css-анимаций производительность лучше, так что даже при использовании js лучше оставить css-анимации.

Comment: Дополню от себя то что еще нашел: 1. Для того чтобы использовать и управлять переменными для css требуется пре/пост-процессор когда на js переменные нативны.  2. Так как скрипты загружаются в последнюю очередь то и перелистывание слайдера(а то и весь слайдер) будет прогружатся также в последнюю  3. Css слайдеры более просты(имхо) в изучении и для создания крутых анимаций необязательно изучать кучу нового синтаксиса.

Comment: 1. Вроде css-переменные слайдеру не очень нужны? 2. Скрипты можно загружать где угодно, главное понимать, что из этого получится. 3. Какого ещё синтаксиса? о_О

Comment: 1. C помощью переменных можно удобно делать delay, время анимации <s>и я считаю что легче написать slide1.hide(), slide2.show() и т.д. а не расписывать slide1{animation: name 2s } + куча кода для простого display(или opacity) на  @keyframes </s>2. Во первых загружать даже min.js если у устройства медленный инет(5 мегабайт, не говорю уже про 200-500кб 2 g инета) перед css достаточно долго. 3. Добавляемого некоторыми готовыми библиотеками синтаксиса, который собсно вызывает слайдер и бывает с помощью него нужно еще характеристики слайдера вписывать.

Comment: [`user:178988 is:a @keyframes`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178988+is%3Aa+%40keyframes)